# How to apply multiple colors Angular 9

Tags: html, css, angular

I use ngFor in button where I got 4 results from data and I expect 4 buttons in the HTML.
How can I apply 4 different colors for this button?

P.S.
[In ngFor colors I receive obj:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzIww.png)

I use Object.values to take only the link from the obj and assign ***colors*** in ***this.img*** where I use it in HTML to display every image when click one of the 4 buttons. That's why I need to apply to every button background-color

[Page in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf78c.jpg)

```
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <img [src]="img">
    </div>

      <div>
        <span class="title-description">Select color:</span>
        <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px;">
          <button *ngFor="let colors of product.image" class="card ml-1" 
                  (click)="changeColor(colors)"
                  style="height: 30px; width: 30px;">
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

changeColor(colors) {
this.img = Object.values(colors);
}
```

Comment: If you check the link in my answer, I think it does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a `color` property to each object in `this.product.image`, with a color code, which you can then use to style your buttons. E.g:

```
products = [
    {color: 'red', path: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150'}, 
    {color: 'green', path: 'https://via.placeholder.com/250'}, 
    {color: 'yellow', path: 'https://via.placeholder.com/350'}, 
    {color: 'blue', path: 'https://via.placeholder.com/450'}
];
```

You can then use `ngStyle` to style each button, using these colors:

```
<button *ngFor="let product of products" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': product.color}" (click)="img = product.path"></button>

<img *ngIf="img" [src]="img">
```

Example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7avua).